# How can I make a clock with pistons in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've been wanting to know how to make a piston clock in Minecraft. I've seen them before, but I don't have a clue how they are made. Is there an easy tutorial or something that I can follow? How can I make one easily?

Comment: The [wiki has designs](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Clock_circuit#Piston_Clocks), but they are more technical-level than tutorial-level.

Comment: A hopper clock would probably be better right now.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a piston clock?  do you mean a clock that tells time?  Or a group of pistons that sends out a redstone pulse at a regular rate?  (The later is the usual interpretation.)

Comment: The digital clock: look at rbaleksandar's answers. Minecraft Pixel Clock item: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlGyGSLRWC0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried searching in YouTube? There is a huge amount of tutorials on this topic. Here is one that I like (remember: creating a clock is not a trivial matter):

Note: this is not a perfect solution since seconds are being skipped
Part 1:

Part 2:

Part 3:

Comment: You're most welcome :) As I mentioned - it's not a trivial matter. If you are not comfortable with red stone circuits and logic, do start with something simpler, gain the required knowledge and build one yourself. The satisfaction will be much greater. ;)